# Weird IP cpnnections on default install

Tags: networking, iptables

I install 14.04 in a VM. I created a log [using these instructions](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/iptables-log-packets/) and did stuff on my computer. I grep out DST=192 and =lo. I saw two ip addresses. 224.0.0.251 and 91.189.92.11.

224.0.0.251 appears to be a [service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12484972/34537). The other is Canonical. Why don't I see any Amazon IPs? AFAIK by default when I do a search it sends my query to amazon. (Removed related question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you elaborate on why you think 91.189.92.11 is a russian IP-address?

The whois entry and the IP-addresses on the hops to that IP indicate, that it is owned by Canonical, located in Great Britain and reverse DNSes to productsearch.ubuntu.com

http://www.whois.com/whois/91.189.92.11

https://ipdb.at/ip/91.189.92.11

http://www.dnsgoodies.com/

Though the server being Russia isn't your problem; productsearch.ubuntu.com is questionable anyway. See: https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2012/10/privacy-ubuntu-1210-amazon-ads-and-data-leaks

Comment: My bad, I googled something that said russia and another that said moscow, russia. Maybe I mistyped it but now when I search I find it Canonical and this site mistakenly says netherlands https://db-ip.com/91.189.92.11

Comment: I plan to. I was still typing and editing ;P. Basically I was looking for leaks mentioned in your linked article. Perfect answer. I wonder what other leaks if any

Comment: I also found that article quite interesting. I thought Canonical would be more cautious about that kind of thing...

Comment: What do you mean by more cautious? It doesn't go straight to amazon thats one big step

Comment: They are still sending potentially sensitive searches for local files over the internet, for all the agencys to collect. Also they them self are able to collect that data. I think that feature is hazardous and they should be more thoughtful with their actions.